# Fedora 34 - Mouse click stops working

Tags: fedora, gnome

I have the same problem as in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/650600/desktop-stops-responding-to-mouse-input-fedora-34)

OS: Fedora 34
Desktop: Gnome 40

My mouse randomly stops working. This doesn't seems to be linked to any application. When this happens I can still see the cursor and move around but the click doesn't work. This is pretty annoying since I can't change the focus. I have to `alt-tab` trough the pages to click on button and focus on input.

This is a software problem since my touchpad doesn't work too.

Comment: I would first look to see if `libinput` is registering the events. This is the library that is used to handle input devices like your mouse and touchpad. Next time this happens, try opening a terminal, and use the following to debug: `sudo libinput debug-events`. This should show events registering as a "`POINTER_BUTTON`" type of event. If `libinput` is seeing the button press events fine, then you can move on to seeing if this is happening at a higher-level layer like GNOME Shell. Basically, it will give you the basis on how to troubleshoot further.